# Почему при плавном скролле к якорю на одной странице в адрес не записывается через решетку айди блока?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
$('.go_to').click( function(){ 
    var scroll_el = $(this).attr('href'); 
    if ($(scroll_el).length != 0) { 
       $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $(scroll_el).offset().top }, 500); 
    }
    return false; 
});
```

Почему при таком методе плавной прокрутки в URL не попадает id блока к которому произошел скроллинг? site.ru/#menu и тд.

Comment: `return false;`

Comment: @Igor Спасибо..